# Can a coroutine be destroyed during evaluation of an inner await expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, coroutine, c++20

According to the standard, a coroutine shall be destroyed only when it is suspended [[dcl.fct.def.coroutine]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11)

> If destroy is called for a coroutine that is not suspended, the program has undefined behavior.

During evaluation of a *await expression* inside a coroutine A suppose this sequence of event corresponding to [[expr.await]/5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await#5.1.1):

1. coroutine A is suspended because *await-ready* is false;
2. before giving control to coroutine A caller, a coroutine B is resumed;
3. once B is also suspended control flows returns to coroutine A caller.

May coroutine A be destroyed after coroutine B is resumed but before it is suspended?

Exemple code:

```
#include <coroutine>

using namespace std;

struct task
    {
    struct promise_type;

    using handle_type = coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    struct promise_type
        {
        handle_type resumer = nullptr; 
        auto
        get_return_object(){
            return task{handle_type::from_promise(*this)};
            }

        auto 
        initial_suspend(){
            return suspend_always {};
            }

        auto 
        unhandled_exception(){}

        auto
        final_suspend(){
            return suspend_always{};
            }

        void 
        return_void() {}

        };


   handle_type handle;

   void await_resume(){
       handle.resume();
   }

   auto
   await_suspend(handle_type h){
       handle.promise().resumer = h;
       return handle;
   }
   auto
   await_ready(){
       return false;
   }

    };


int main(){

  task coroutine_B = [&coroutine_B]() ->task
            {
            coroutine_B.handle.promise().resumer.destroy();
            co_return;
            }();//coroutine B supended at initial suspend

  task coroutine_A = [&coroutine_B]() ->task 
            {
            co_await coroutine_B;//set coroutine_B resumer to coroutine_A handle
                                 //then resume coroutine_B.
            }();//coroutine A supended at initial suspend.

  coroutine_A.handle.resume();//execute co_await coroutine_B;
                              //is this UB?

}
```

As can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/FM2iCm), the code compiles and seems to run without any troubles.

On the other hand this apparently equivalent version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_rZ3pz) crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard in [dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11) says

> The coroutine state is destroyed when ... the `destroy` member function of a coroutine handle that refers to the coroutine is invoked... If `destroy` is called for a coroutine that is not suspended, the program has undefined behavior.

In your example `destroy` is called from `coroutine_B` for the coroutine handle of `coroutine_A`, which is suspended because of `co_await`. So the `destroy` member function is called for a suspended coroutine, so there is no undefined behavior in it.

And indeed Clang, GCC, MSVC all compile and execute the code fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zxePvsvx1

> On the other hand this apparently equivalent version here crashes.

Here the problem is that `coroutine_B.resumer` contains `nullptr` address in GCC so `coroutine_B.resumer.destroy()` is undefined behavior. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T8aa45ez1